# How to read from a file using fstream

Tags: c++

```cpp
void Tutorial() {
    fstream myFile;
    myFile.open("Tutorial.txt", ios::in);
    if (myFile.is_open()) {
        string line;
        while (getline(myFile, line))
        {
            std::cout << line << endl;
        }
        myFile.close();
    }
}
```

I have a file inside the folder called `tutorial.txt`, but it does not print out the characters in the console when the function is called.

Comment: platform? Windows, Mac, Linux?

Comment: What folder????

Comment: windows and the project folder

Comment: IDE? Visual Studio? VSCode, ??

Comment: visual studio not code

Comment: in the debug properties of the project set the working directory to where the file is

Comment: where do i find that in debug i cant see

Comment: `"Tutorial.txt"` does not specify the starting folder, so the path is relative to the current working directory. The working directory is generally decided by whatever spawned your process, and may have absolutely no relationship to the location of the executable, the source files used to generate the executable, or the phase of the moon. For example, if I have A program in /path/to/executable and from /totally/different/location I run /path/to/executable/my_program, the program will look for /totally/different/location/Tutorial.txt

Comment: @Kameron - your question isn't bad, it's how you asked it. A descriptive title like `"How to set working directory in Visual Studio"` would have immediately oriented people to what you were asking. Then providing the details of the version you were using (VS2017 - VS2022) in the question itself would have eliminated guesswork. (that will save most downvotes -- not that it hurts right now with a rep of `1` -- but going forward)

Answer (score 1):

Set the working directory here (right click , properties on the project)

[image]

Comment: Worth mentioning that will set it for the `"Debug"` configuration and `x64` build. You can also set it to apply to all-configurations. (may save a couple of "Huh??" moments...)